# Jekyll. Liquid: Specify active/current state for exceptional nav item

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Website has multiple backgrounds. To make navigation more intuitive additional class (in this example in CSS will target `.active.projects`) needs to be added to one of the nav items (in this case, /projects/).

My take which does not work is the 2nd `elsif`.
`/` is used for homepage.

```
      {% assign links = site.data.navigation %}
      {% for link in links %}
        {% assign class = nil %}
        {% if page.url == link.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active' %}
          {% elsif link.url != '/' and page.url contains link.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active' %}
          {% elsif link.url == '/projects/' and page.url contains link.url %}
          {% assign class = 'active projects' %}
        {% endif %}
          <li class="{{ class }}">
            <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}{{ link.url }}">{{ link.name }}</a>
          </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

navigation.yml

```
- name: Home
  url:  /
- name: Blog
  url: /blog/
- name: Projects
  url: /projects/
- name: About
  url: /about/
```

How to specify active state for exceptional nav item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order:

```
  {% assign links = site.data.navigation %}
  {% for link in links %}
    {% assign class = nil %}
    {% if page.url == link.url and link.url != '/projects/' %}
      {% assign class = 'active' %}
    {% elsif link.url == '/projects/' and page.url contains link.url %}
      {% assign class = 'active projects' %}
    {% elsif link.url != '/' and page.url contains link.url %}          
      {% assign class = 'active' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out! Interesting, this code ignores class "projects" and adds only "active". Both classes are displayed so far only by this code ibb.co/VwRqJ7F (screenshot from editor). But classes are added to home ibb.co/t8WRLjW (screenshot from browsers inspect element). Changed order, same thing :/

Comment: This does depend on your permalink setting in _config.yml

Comment: Now both classes adds as should! Only always there is another "active" for home (/).

Comment: Wuhuu! For last "elsif" changed page.url to link.url and now my navigation works as expected. Thanks for being along! Much appreciated!